# Linkedin APIs query on other users' profile

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am trying out Linkedin's REST API console. After I authenticate, I am able to query only my own profile data fields. As today (May 2017), is it possible to access other user's data by using a query of this sort? https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=OTHERUSERID?format=json